# OpenJPA: How to eagerly fetch two-level nested associations?

Tags: java, openjpa

I'm trying to efficiently fetch a two-level nested association using OpenJPA 2.2. Basically, I have one `A` that has one `B` that has many `C`:

```java
@Entity
public class A {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<C> cs;
}

@Entity
public class C {
    ...
}
```

My JPQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT a
FROM A a
WHERE a.id = some condition
```

I set the [EagerFetchMode](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_perfpack_eager.html) to "PARALLEL" in order to have a second query that retrieves the `Cs` of all the `Bs`:

```xml
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.EagerFetchMode" value="parallel"/>
<property name="org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.EagerFetchMode" value="PARALLEL"/>
```

The problem is that openjpa is generating n+1 queries instead of 2: one for the `As` and `Bs` and one for each `C`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
    ON a.b_id = b.id 
WHERE some condition
```

and n times

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c 
WHERE c.b_id = x
```

**How can I make openjpa issue two queries instead of n+1?**